# Asp.net mvc route for short url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am going to make short url for some specific pages rest of site will remain same .

So I have following things

```
public class publiccontroller {
  Public ActionResult GetPublicUrl(){
    // This method generates a Random Characters and make url of that random character 
    // So suppose after this method i have a url for public like this : www.abc.de/HS56J
  }
  Public ActionResult ServePublic(string publickey){ // publickey will be = HS56J

  }
 }
```

So what will be the route for this and i don't want to change my existing site functionality

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The routing code is simple:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SomeRoutingName",
              url: "{publickey}",
              defaults: new { controller = "public", action = "ServePublic" });
```

Difficult part is to decide where to put it in your routing order. I don't know how your current routing looks like, so it is hard to give accurate answer. If you only have the default routing, then you should put the code above in front of the default routing.

Keep in mind that this will cause some url no longer goes to the home page, like /Home. If you still want them to work, you have to manually route them. Or if the random URL follows some pattern(regex), you should define constraint to avoid false routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SomeRoutingName",
              url: "{publickey}",
              defaults: new { controller = "public", action = "ServePublic" },
              constraints: new { publickey= "" }); // Put regex for your random key
```